# How to get value through javascript using selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to get the element value from browser to web driver. i.e. whenever I click on browser it should send value of that element to selenium web driver.

Comment: Please provide an example what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: look what i want is that if user click any where in side browser any where it should send its value to selenium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to get some value from browser, you can use

String str = Driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the object").getText();

Comment: Thanks Pooja! It really helped me